# How do I find and group time chains in 36 seconds?

Tags: mysql, date, time, range, chain

- I have a date table.
- I want to find and grouping dates with 36 seconds difference.
- is there a difference of 36 seconds between the previous date and the
  next date?
- If it is, it will be a group until the end of the chain.
- If the 36-second chain is broken, it starts a new group.
- if there is no chain for 36 seconds, finisDate and dateRangeIDs
  returns null

I can do this with software, but it is time consuming. I need to do over MySQL.

My date table (date > %d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s);

```
ID  |   Date
----+-----------------------
246 |   11.08.2014 07:54:38
247 |   11.08.2014 07:55:11
248 |   11.08.2014 07:55:45
249 |   11.08.2014 07:56:20
250 |   11.08.2014 07:56:53
251 |   11.08.2014 07:57:26
252 |   11.08.2014 07:58:01
253 |   11.08.2014 07:58:35
254 |   11.08.2014 07:59:10
255 |   11.08.2014 07:59:49
256 |   11.08.2014 07:59:58
257 |   11.08.2014 08:00:15
258 |   11.08.2014 08:00:23
259 |   11.08.2014 08:00:58
260 |   11.08.2014 08:01:01
261 |   11.08.2014 08:01:08
262 |   11.08.2014 09:12:11
```

Expected result:

```
mainID  |   startDate               |   finishDate              |   dateRangeIDs
--------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------
246     |   11.08.2014 07:54:38     |   11.08.2014 07:59:10     |   247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254 
255     |   11.08.2014 07:59:49     |   11.08.2014 08:01:08     |   256,257,258,259,260,261
262     |   11.08.2014 09:12:11     |   NULL                    |   NULL
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry fiddle is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609e15/1

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sql server 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method uses `lag()` to get the previous date value.  That is not available in most versions of MySQL.  A correlated subquery is really painful to make work.  The last option is variables:

```
select min(id) as mainid, min(date), max(date),
       group_concat(id order by id) as ids
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@prev_date > date - interval 36 second,
                         if(@prev_date := date, @grp, @grp),  -- keep the group the same
                         if(@prev_date := date, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by date
           ) t cross join
           (select @prev_date := '', @grp := 0) params
     ) t
group by grp;
```

EDIT:

You can remove the main id by doing:

```
select min(id) as mainid, min(date), max(date),
       substr(group_concat(id order by id), length(min(id)) + 1) as ids
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was a close result. The grouping IDs not sequential and each group also receives its own ID How do I resolve it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609e15/7

Comment: The first problem is easily solved.  The second requires quite a bit of work.  It is really worth it?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. You saved hours.